# how to up the col grid in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

[image: 3 col in medium view in bootstrap]

i have 3 col in medium view in bootstrap shown in above image ie.

[image]

i want to achieve this type of view in small view is col-sm-*

my code is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12">C</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
</div>
```

IN THIS way i can achieve my target in medium view but cant achieve in small view.how can i achieve the both view as well as in medium and small view as shown in image.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading [bootstrap css doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete) also [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

But try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="all a col-sm-12 col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="all b col-sm-12 col-md-6">B</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="all c col-sm-12 col-md-6">C</div>
</div>
```

You can remove the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` if you don't care about the height mismatch
Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3q4knayp/8/embedded/result/)

Comment: thaks for reply but i want A->B->C in small screen not same type as pic 1 i want pic 2 IN small screen @Roko

Comment: still B comes after A->C. i WANT C in between A & B ie. A->C->B @Roko

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a stretch, but you could try this:-

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 visible-sm visible-xs">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-12">C</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
</div>
```

Frankly, I can't think of any other solution using just HTML and CSS. Although, if scripts were involved, it would be a different case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't assign columns without rows, so you should have something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right col-xs-12">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">C</div>
</div>
```

So you pull right your B Div (therefore not clearing the next div, and spacing it out). And with col-xs-12 you assure that float won't be present in mobile.

[Heres a pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/jbmqrE)

Now, if you want to remain with your code, I guess [Shan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955946/how-to-up-the-col-grid-in-bootstrap/32957169#32957169) answer is the best one.

Well, you could have the height of B and work with margins so the positioning go right, but that isn't considered best practices and could cause some bugs.